# Sql query that uses its own result within itself

Tags: mysql, database

any help would be appreciated with this query I'm trying to write in mysql. I have two tables:

```
files (id, name, subject, size, day, hour, username) and 
friendships (user1, user2).
```

I would like to select `10 most recent` rows (in terms of id) from the table `files` where the `username` from each row is present in the table `friendships`, with the `second column` of `friendships` being equal to some `name 'x'`.

I am trying to use this statement:

```
SELECT name, 
       subject, 
       size, 
       day, 
       hour, 
       username 
FROM   files 
WHERE  username IN ((SELECT user1 
                     FROM   friendships 
                     WHERE  user2 = 'x') 
                    UNION ALL 
                    (SELECT user2 
                     FROM   friendships 
                     WHERE  user1 = 'x')) 
ORDER  BY id DESC 
LIMIT  10;
```

However, i get an error. What is wrong with this and is there a better method?

Comment: Whats the error and `MySql` or `Sql-server`

Comment: Mysql. the error is 1064. near 'UNION ALL (SELECT user2 FROM friendships WHERE user1='x')) ORDER BY id DESC LIMI' at line 1

Comment: You need aliases as it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the braces.

```
SELECT name, 
       subject, 
       size, 
       day, 
       hour, 
       username 
FROM   files 
WHERE  username IN (SELECT user1 
                     FROM   friendships 
                     WHERE  user2 = 'x' 
                    UNION ALL 
                    SELECT user2 
                     FROM   friendships 
                     WHERE  user1 = 'x') 
ORDER  BY id DESC 
LIMIT  10;
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what is causing your error, but there is a better method.  Split this into two operations.  I generally use `exists` (although `in` is probably fine):

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM friendships fs WHERE fs.user2 = 'x' and fs.user1 = files.username) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM friendships fs WHERE fs.user1 = 'x' and fs.user2 = files.username)
```

This formulation will allow the query to take better advantage of indexes, in particular on `friendships(user1, user2)` and `friendships(user2, user1)` (yes, both are desirable in this case).

Comment: so the final statement would look like? where exists select (query here) ?

Comment: It would look like your query with this `where` clause.